# Need suggestion for to write QString to JSON format

Tags: json, qt

I need suggestion for my requirement of writting the QString data to json format.

Im reading data  from  dbus which returns me data in QString and QVariantMap and im using the data for my Qt GUI. 
at the same time i have to feed the data to a web application .

the web application developer asked me to give the data in JSON format so he can read and write the data in his application .

so can you people suggest me a good way of writtin the data which comes from DBUS every time from  DBUS  to  the JSON format .

Please provide me if any alternate solution or how i can synchronously write a JSON file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/json.html). It adds the support for JSON format in QT if you are using Qt 5.
I have not used it yet, but might be helpful.
The example of using the JSON with Qt can be found in [this example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcore-savegame-example.html).

Comment: thank you  i can able to do it now ..im using your library .. it is easy for me to parse now ..

Answer (score 2):

A JSON object is quite similar to a map. If you're using Qt 5 writing data to JSON objects is very easy:

```
// String you would like to send to the web application
QString myString("Hi there!");

// JSON object used to store the data to be sent to the web application
QJsonObject myObject;

myObject.insert("key used by the web application", myString);
QJsonDocument myDocument(myObject);
```

At this point you can use myDocument to obtain the JSON representation of your data, by means of toJson() method. As an example:

```
qDebug() << myDocument.toJson();
```

produces this output:

```
{
    "key used by the web application": "Hi there!"
}
```